Understanding simple calibration of Hull-White process
I've encountered issues with understanding how to calibrate the Hull-White model without Quantlib package. I want to calibrate this model for the time series of short-rate ($r_1, \cdots,r_n$).
I will be very thankful, if some articles can be provided (where calibration is described in the most simpliest language)
